# Create excel file from complex xml-schema

Tags: excel, xsd

I'm looking at the feasibility of using an Excel file for loading data into the EPA GHG schema (ghg_subpartp_inputs_v1.0.xsd) for defining the XML Subpartp Inputs data.

I'm not well versed or practiced in using Excel and xml-schemas.

The SubpartP schema has nested complex elements, and it won't be accepted into Excel via the XML Maps facility.

Error message: "Cannot Load the specified XML or schema source."

I'm thinking it is because it is a partial schema that is meant to be included in others?

Here is the schema itself:

Schema Name  : ghg_subpartp_inputs_v1.0.xsd
        Description  : Inputs Verifier Tool - XML schema for Subpart P inputs

```
<xsd:complexType name="SubpartPInputsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="SubpartPUnitInputs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="UnitName" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Values">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="EquationP1FeedstockInputs" type="EquationP1FeedstockInputsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                <xsd:element name="EquationP2FeedstockInputs" type="EquationP2FeedstockInputsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                <xsd:element name="EquationP3FeedstockInputs" type="EquationP3FeedstockInputsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:unique name="UniqueSubpartPFeedstockName">
                <xsd:selector xpath="Values/*"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="FeedstockName"/>
            </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EquationP1FeedstockInputsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FeedstockName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Values">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="MassOrVolume" type="MassOrVolumeIndicatorType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="EquationP1MonthlyInputs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="12">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="MonthName" type="MonthNameList"/>
                                <xsd:element name="Values">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="Mass" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg of fuel or feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element name="Volume" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: scf (at standard conditions of 68 degrees F and atmospheric pressure) of fuel or feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element name="CarbonContent" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg C per kg of fuel or feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element name="MolecularWeight" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg/kg-mole</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:unique name="UniqueEquationP1MonthName">
                <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="MonthName"/>
            </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EquationP2FeedstockInputsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FeedstockName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Values">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="MassOrVolume" type="MassOrVolumeIndicatorType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="EquationP2MonthlyInputs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="12">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="MonthName" type="MonthNameList"/>
                                <xsd:element name="Values">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="Mass" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg of fuel or feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element name="Volume" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: gallons of fuel or feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element name="CarbonContent" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg C per kg of fuel or feedstock if measured as mass, or kg C per gallon of fuel or feedstock if measured as volume</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:unique name="UniqueEquationP2MonthName">
                <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="MonthName"/>
            </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EquationP3FeedstockInputsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FeedstockName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Values">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="EquationP3MonthlyInputs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="12">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="MonthName" type="MonthNameList"/>
                                <xsd:element name="Values">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="Mass" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg of fuel and feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element name="CarbonContent" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:annotation>
                                                    <xsd:documentation>Required units of measure for this equation input: kg C per kg of fuel and feedstock</xsd:documentation>
                                                </xsd:annotation>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:unique name="UniqueEquationP3MonthName">
                <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="MonthName"/>
            </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

What should I be doing to create the Excel file that will create an acceptible XML for this schema?

Comment: Click on the button Details in the error message to get detailled error descriptions. Your schema is incomplete. First error is namespace xsd is not declared. Then XSD-Type MonthNameList is not declared. Then I have give up.

Comment: Thank you for the reply; one of the issues is that the Details button is disabled.  I'll try adding 'proper' namespace, etc.